# How to Copy a Container and its contents to AWS bucket using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new bee to `AWS Bucket`. Please consider my content in the post.

I have more than 100 GB of files stored on a `Windows Azure`.

It has some what folowing structure:

```
http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/10/captureimage/124084.png
http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/10/captureimage/124086.png

http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/12/eab0d364-6112201550706PM.JPG
http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/12/eac15464-d1122015124429PM.JPG

http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/12/small/1c03d1bd-5112201541616PM.JPG
http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/12/small/1c149656-5112201550424PM.JPG

http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/12/thumbs/00a24075-b112201535134PM.JPG
http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/2015/1/12/thumbs/016226a0-2112201592913AM.JPG
```

As now we are migrating another server. ***We need to copy these all files and its contents on AWS Bucket*** using C#.

Also, i have a all the `URLS` of these `links` to a `text file.` So, **can we copy the files directly from `AZURE` to `AWS Bucket`? or need to Download it on local and then need to Upload to `AWS Bucket`?**

Any suggestions?

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Amazon S3's [Put Object REST API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html), I believe it doesn't support fetching a URL's contents and saving that as an object (which Azure Blob Service does support BTW). So your only option would be to download blobs from Azure Storage to local computer and then upload them into Amazon S3.